# android radiobutton alignment

Tags: android, layout, radio-button

I'm trying to work out how to correctly align text to radio buttons. I have a number of radio buttons laid out vertically in a radio group and a TextView for each radio button that should line up with the radio button. The problem i'm finding is that because the radio buttons are in their own RadioGroup layout I can't reference the RadioButton so it lines up with the TextView. Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to nest a LinearLayout inside the RadioGroup and put the TextView and RadioButton within it?  I haven't tried myself so I don't know if it works.

Comment: The layout works correctly but the radio buttons no longer function as if they are in a radio group

Comment: That's true.  Just tried it myself.  You could handle the button states manually and lose the RadioGroup.

Comment: How about a TableLayout with two columns.  First column contains multiple rows with your TextViews and the second column spans column ones rows and contains your RadioGroup.

Comment: That would probably work. I have done something similar with a horizontal linear layout that contains a vertical linear layout with the text on the left and a radio group on the right. This is working but both seem rather inefficient and a bit meesy.

Comment: It does doesn't it.  I don't know if the layoutopt sdk tool would help give any clues as to a better way.  I haven't actually used it myself.

Comment: Gave the layoutopt tool a go. doesn't tell me anything so I guess all my layouts are perfect. That or the more likely possibility that it just doesn't work well on complex examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Relative Layout instead of a Linear Layout. In relative layouts, the positioning of a view is always relative to another. That way, you can define the position of your TextView, and then anchor the RadioGroup to it using layout_below, layout_above, layout_toRightOf, layout_toLeftOf, etc.

Answer (score 0):

every radiobutton has a text by default: `android:text`. do you really need another textview for each radiobutton?

Comment: Yes. I need the text on the left.

Comment: Ok. Can you put a LinearLayout inside a RadioGroup? If so may be you can put a radio button and textview inside the LinearLayout and use a LinearLayout for every radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

A RadioGroup is derived from ViewGroup - you could enumerate the children (RadioButtons) using the getChildCount and getChildAt methods and, in turn, as RadioButtons are derived from View, use getBottom / getTop to find each RadioButton's relative position within the RadioGroup.